# Why NEXT_DATA script in nex.tjs web app exposing my secret variables used on client side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, serverside-javascript

I built and deploy a next.js web app in which I very carefully choose my environment variables and put them in the next.config.js file, and ignored them using gitignore file. Now when I opened the inspect window on the browser the NEXT_DATA script exposing all my secret variables. Can someone suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an environment variable for production as you do you have to create a file
.env
where you have to put the variable you want to use
here is an example of how to create and use the environment variable

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv

remember to create in .env file then add your variable